# Get models that do not contain another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models `A` and `B` that have `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between them. I want to get all instances of `A` that are not associated by current `B`:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  def find_that_does_not_have(model_b)
    ...
  end
end
```

I think I have to use somethig like this:

```
find(:all, :conditions => [])
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then one solution would be to make a corresponding class-method:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.find_that_does_not_have(model_b)
        (A.all.map {|a| a unless a.bs.include?(model_b)}).compact
    end
end
```

So you can ask like this:

```
model_b = B.find(your_id)
A.find_that_does_not_have(model_b)
```

It smells like a job for a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope), but I guess I'm too noob to represent it like this at the moment :)

**EDIT:** With the help of user @0v3rc10ck3d I came up with a scope like this:

```
scope :find_that_does_not_have_b, lambda {|model_b| joins(:bs).where("b_id != #{model_b.id}")}
```

but it returns all model A objects regarding to **relations** so repetitions exist. Therefore you should add `uniq` while requesting:

```
A.find_that_does_not_have_b(model_b).uniq
```

Comment: Did you changed `bs` corresponding to your model B (`bs` represents you model B name in plural)? For ex User-model would be `users` in that case.

Comment: `bs` is the term he gave...He probably meant the association. User has _many roles, so user_object.roles. Something of that kind. a_object.b_objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope : find_that_does_not_have_b, lambda {|b_id| joins(:association_table).where('association_table.b_id != b_id')}
```

Might do the job. Couldn't test it. Call it like :

```
A.find_that_does_not_have_b(b_id)
```

Just clarifying something here. So you want a list of all A objects which is not associated to a given B object. right ?

Comment: it is very dependent on table names. If I have abstract model that has a lot of children and I want this method to be common for each of them?

Comment: I am not sure if its going to do anything different from the answer above. The answer above calls A.all and loops through each record which is as costly as it gets. This instead of looping gives you the same thing as a result of one single join query. Since it is has many belongs to many i assume there is a table that has the associations stored.

a.bs is doing nothing but going into that table and fetching the records.

Comment: I'm not sure why but I'm not able to recreate the same wanted result with scope anymore :/ maybe I accidentally used my class method name instead of my scope name and saw that it gives me the wanted result. Anyhow I tried quite a lot to get the same answer but all I got with the join-scope were the **relational a-s** that does not contain `b_object`. But that means repetitive results with some `a_object`-s that actually might include `b_object` but not in **current relation**. Class method, on the contrary, will **only** give those A-objects that certainly don't contain any current b_object.

Comment: But yes- basically it is the same scope but I made some fixes (including `joins(:bs_table)` not `:association_table`. Still I don't see any other less-costly way to get the result than above-mentioned class-method.